# Snowflake javascript procedure doesn't use the session on which it was called from java application

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a procedure written in javascript. The procedure is called, multiple times, from java using snowflake jdbc implementation. We have observed that the procedures runs in different sessions that the session in java application, because of which the  query tag we set in java is not inherited in procedure for queries executing inside procedure. Can you suggest a way to achieve the same.

Comment: Are you running the procedure with owner's or caller's rights? Running with owner's rights (which is the default) cannot use the same session.

Comment: I was running with caller's right only. However, I am able to fix this issue by adding query tag in connection url. Thanks for your response.